# Scope of variables in java/android code.

Tags: java, android, variables

My android code looks like this:

```
boolean b;
Context context;
//inside onCreate method:
b =false;
context= getApplicationContext();

//outside onCreate method
public void c(){

new Thread(new Runnable(){

boolean d = false;

public void run(){

//inside a try/catch block:
try{

d = true;
b =d; // b was defined inside onCreate

}catch{

} 

}
}).start();

if(b)Toast.makeText(context,"hello whale",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
else Toast.makeText(context,"hello Lion",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  


} //end of method c
```

The toast message that prints is "hello Lion". I dont know why since b has been set to true inside the try/catch block.  I don't know what could be missing.

I know is something simple, but I don't know what it is. I need "hello whale" to print on the phone screen.

I know the try part of the try/catch block is executing since I have an outputstream writing to my localhost database. All the fields that need to be written to have been written to by the outputstream.

thanks for any advice

Comment: Check with breakpoints if b is actually set to true before it is queried.

Comment: What do you mean breakpoints? @F43nd1r

Comment: Breakpoints allow to pause execution of code. You can find plenty on that with your favorite search engine.

Answer (score 0):

There is no guarantee that the code in the runnable will be done executing before the Toast block executes. It just means that the thread is "started" before the Toast block. If you really need the thread (I'm assuming this is proxy code for something you're trying to accomplish something with multiple thread) use join method on the thread. Can't think of a reason to use a single thread.

```
new Thread(new Runnable(){

boolean d = false;

public void run(){

//inside a try/catch block:
try{

d = true;
b =d; // b was defined inside onCreate

}catch{

} 
}
}).start().join();
```